# WPF: Change ComboBox arrow button color in XAML

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, controltemplate

I want to change my `ComboBox` `Arrow` color while `Mouse Over`.
Currently i only found this little `Squesre` around the Arrow and change it while `Mouse Over`is `True`:

```
<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="White"/>
</Trigger>
```

[image]

`Mouse Over` is `false`:

```
<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
</Trigger>
```

[image]

- Edit

  ```
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate">
          <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush}" 
            CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 1" 
            Background="Transparent" />
              <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="1, 1, 1, 1" BorderBrush="#444" Name="ButtonBorder"
            CornerRadius="0, 0, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 0" 
            Background="#FF998F8F" />

              <Path Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" 
          Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Fill="#444"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          </Grid>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gainsboro"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="Transparent"/>
                  <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Gray"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                  <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FF8D979E"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledBorderBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Shape.Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#999"/>
              </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >
          <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
          <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
          <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
          <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
          <Setter Property="Control.Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                      <Grid>
                          <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2"
              ClickMode="Press" Focusable="False"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"/>

                          <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" Margin="5, 3, 23, 3" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"                              
                            Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>

                          <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Margin="3, 3, 23, 3"                     
                           IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                           Visibility="Hidden" Background="Transparent"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Focusable="True" >
                              <TextBox.Template>
                                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox" >
                                      <Border Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" />
                                  </ControlTemplate>
                              </TextBox.Template>
                          </TextBox>
                          <!-- Popup showing items -->
                          <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom"
                             Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True"
                             IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"
                             PopupAnimation="Slide" >
                              <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                  <Border Name="DropDownBorder" Background="Transparent" Margin="0, 1, 0, 0"
                      CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                      BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxNormalBorderBrush}"/>
                                  <ScrollViewer Margin="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                      <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                  </ScrollViewer>
                              </Grid>
                          </Popup>
                      </Grid>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                              <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                              <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                              <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                              <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden"/>
                          </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
      <!-- endregion -->
  ```

BTW i also want to change the `Border` color with `Mouse Over`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to right click the combobox and choose edit template -> edit copy (which will give you the entire template for the combobox) then you need to find "ComboBoxToggleButton" template, and you will find a path inside it, you can then change its color or even replace it with a different vector if you wanted to).

Comment: Still cannot find how to change the border color (see my edit for the whole controller style)

Comment: Do you mean the Toggle button border? you could change it by simply changing the borderbrush property on that button. Is you want it all on mouse over then you need some triggers to be set up.